# Count groups of values in Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas (`pandas==0.23.4`) datetime-indexed dataframe `df` with a column named `value_id`.

`value_id` contains groups of float values (either `5.0` or `6.0`) and groups of `NaN`. I would like to count the number of continuous groups for both `5.0` and `6.0`. The groups must contain at least three consecutive values.

For example:

```
In [1]: print df.value_id
timestamp
2019-01-06 17:42:08    NaN
2019-01-06 17:45:08    5.0
2019-01-06 17:48:08    5.0
2019-01-06 17:51:08    5.0
2019-01-06 17:54:08    NaN
2019-01-06 17:57:08    NaN
2019-01-06 18:00:08    NaN
2019-01-06 18:03:08    NaN
2019-01-06 18:06:08    NaN
2019-01-06 18:09:08    NaN
2019-01-06 18:12:08    6.0
2019-01-06 18:15:08    6.0
2019-01-06 19:54:09    NaN
2019-01-06 19:57:09    5.0
2019-01-06 20:00:08    5.0
2019-01-06 20:03:08    5.0
2019-01-06 20:06:09    NaN
2019-01-06 20:09:08    NaN
2019-01-06 20:12:08    NaN
2019-01-06 20:15:09    NaN
2019-01-06 20:18:08    NaN
2019-01-06 20:21:09    NaN
2019-01-06 20:24:09    NaN
2019-01-07 19:09:07    NaN
2019-01-07 19:12:06    NaN
2019-01-07 19:15:06    5.0
2019-01-07 19:18:06    5.0
2019-01-07 19:21:07    5.0
2019-01-07 19:24:07    5.0
2019-01-07 19:27:07    NaN
2019-01-07 19:30:07    NaN
2019-01-07 19:33:06    NaN
2019-01-07 19:36:07    NaN
2019-01-07 19:39:07    NaN
2019-01-07 19:42:06    NaN
2019-01-07 19:45:06    NaN
2019-01-07 19:48:06    NaN
2019-01-07 19:51:06    6.0
2019-01-07 19:54:07    6.0
2019-01-07 19:57:06    6.0
Name: value_id, dtype: float64
```

If I had two variables named `count1` (for the 5.0 value groups) and `count2` (for the 6.0 value groups), the resulting counts assigned for the above example would be:

`count1`: 3

`count2`: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC create the group key with `cumsum`  then we just do `value_counts`

```
s.groupby(s.isnull().cumsum()).value_counts().ge(3).sum(level=1)
Out[1026]: 
timestamp
5.0    3.0
6.0    1.0
Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most elegant, but you can use `shift` to both check that the next two items are the same value, and that the previous value is *not* part of the same group:

```py
df['fives'] = ((df['timestamp'] == 5) & (df['timestamp'].shift(-1) == 5)
                & (df['timestamp'].shift(-2) == 5)
                & (df['timestamp'].shift(1) != 5)).astype(int)
df['sixes'] = ((df['timestamp'] == 6) & (df['timestamp'].shift(-1) == 6)
                & (df['timestamp'].shift(-2) == 6)
                & (df['timestamp'].shift(1) != 6)).astype(int)

df[['fives','sixes']].sum()
```

```
fives    3
sixes    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I think you intended to have `df['value_id']`. `timestamp` is the name of the datetime index. But yes, this works.

Comment: @PJW That's how your sample data copied into pandas with `read_clipboard` - a bit of laziness on my part to not rename it. WeNYoBen's solution is definitely more elegant.